# How to update list in Flutter BLoC

Tags: flutter, dart, bloc, cubit, flutter-cubit

I can't update my list in Flutter BLoC
I have a list of 'Boards' that contain another list and my problem is when I change the value of done's a property in the checklist, It does not apply my changes
Even the board's properties won't change and the value of that is not 'emitted'

My State Code :

```
part of 'boards_cubit.dart';

enum BoardsStatus { initial, loading, success, error }

class BoardsState extends Equatable {
  final BoardsStatus status;
  final BoardScreenType screenType;
  final List<Board> todoBoards;
  final List<Board> doingBoards;
  final List<Board> doneBoards;
  final List<Board> archiveBoards;

  const BoardsState({
    required this.status,
    required this.todoBoards,
    required this.screenType,
    required this.doingBoards,
    required this.doneBoards,
    required this.archiveBoards,
  });

  factory BoardsState.initial(BoardScreenType screenType) =>  BoardsState(
        status: BoardsStatus.initial,
        todoBoards: [],
        screenType: screenType,
        doingBoards: [],
        doneBoards: [],
        archiveBoards: [],
      );

  @override
  List<Object?> get props => [
        status,
        todoBoards,
        screenType,
        doingBoards,
        doneBoards,
        archiveBoards,
      ];

  BoardsState copyWith({
    BoardsStatus? status,
    List<Board>? todoBoards,
    BoardScreenType? screenType,
    List<Board>? doingBoards,
    List<Board>? doneBoards,
    List<Board>? archiveBoards,
  }) {
    return BoardsState(
      status: status ?? this.status,
      todoBoards: todoBoards ?? this.todoBoards,
      screenType: screenType ?? this.screenType,
      doingBoards: doingBoards ?? this.doingBoards,
      doneBoards: doneBoards ?? this.doneBoards,
      archiveBoards: archiveBoards ?? this.archiveBoards,
    );
  }
}
```

My Cubit Code :

```
import 'package:bloc/bloc.dart';
import 'package:equatable/equatable.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:timely/futures/timely/domain/entities/board.dart';
import 'package:timely/futures/timely/domain/repositories/timely_repository.dart';
import 'package:timely/futures/timely/presentation/boards/screens/board_screen.dart';

part 'boards_state.dart';

class BoardsCubit extends Cubit<BoardsState> {
  final TimelyRepository repository;

  BoardsCubit({required this.repository, required BoardScreenType screenType})
      : super(BoardsState.initial(screenType)) {
    getBoards();
  }

  @override
  void onChange(Change<BoardsState> change) {
    super.onChange(change);
    debugPrint(
        'change state from ${change.currentState} to ${change.nextState}');
  }

  Future<void> getBoards() async {
    await Future.delayed(const Duration(microseconds: 0));
    emit(state.copyWith(status: BoardsStatus.loading));
    try {
      final res = await repository.getTodoBoard();
      final doingBoards = await repository.getDoingBoard();
      final doneBoards = await repository.getDoneBoard();
      final archiveBoards = await repository.getArchiveBoard();
      res.fold(
          (l) => emit(state.copyWith(status: BoardsStatus.error)),
          (r) => emit(state.copyWith(
                status: BoardsStatus.success,
                todoBoards: r,
              )));
      doingBoards.fold(
          (l) => emit(state.copyWith(status: BoardsStatus.error)),
          (r) => emit(state.copyWith(
                status: BoardsStatus.success,
                doingBoards: r,
              )));
      doneBoards.fold(
          (l) => emit(state.copyWith(status: BoardsStatus.error)),
          (r) => emit(state.copyWith(
                status: BoardsStatus.success,
                doneBoards: r,
              )));
      archiveBoards.fold(
          (l) => emit(state.copyWith(status: BoardsStatus.error)),
          (r) => emit(state.copyWith(
                status: BoardsStatus.success,
                archiveBoards: r,
              )));
    } catch (e) {
      emit(state.copyWith(status: BoardsStatus.error));
    }
  }

  void updateTask(int index, String boardId) {
    List<Board> newBoards = [...state.todoBoards];

    for (int i = 0; i < newBoards.length; i++) {
      if (newBoards[i].id == boardId) {
        newBoards[i].checklist?[index].done = !(newBoards[i].checklist?[index].done??false);
      }
    }
    emit(state.copyWith(todoBoards: newBoards));
  }
}
```